# I am uploading the image file in Angular Js to call the java api but my form data is not hitting the api

Tags: angularjs

controller:

```
$scope.fileToUpload = function(input) {
if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        CommonService.uploadContactImage.upload({
            fileName : input.files[0].name
        }, input.files[0], function(data) {

        });
    }
}
```

Service:

```
uploadContactImage:function(input){
    console.log("game image");
    var req = $http({method: 'POST', url: options.api.base_url + '/gameimageupload/',
      dataType: 'json', headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}})
                .success(function (data)
                {
                    console.log("data" + data);
                    return data;
                });
```

Comment: File can not be uploaded such way. Use `FormData`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: Have a look at this article: https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

If you take a good look at your code you will see that there are quite a few things wrong with it. For example, you have defined in your service an `uploadContactImage` function which takes a single Javascript object as argument (input), while in your controller you attempt to call `CommonService.uploadContactImage.upload(...)` instead of `CommonService.uploadContactImage(...)`. Additionally, even if the `uploadContactImage` function was called correctly it doesn't actually do anything with its argument, ie. the `input` object is never used in the function body.

These issues aside you cannot submit a file to the server just by adding it to the body of a `POST` request the way you (seem to be) trying to do. Without going into too much detail here, in order to upload a file from the browser a request with content type `multipart/form-data` needs to be submitted, which will contain your file as well as the necessary HTTP headers for the server to identify it and parse it correctly. I suppose you could try and construct this request yourself, however it's not a task for the faint-hearted. What I would suggest instead is to use one of the many file upload modules available for Angular.js. A [Google search](https://www.google.gr/search?q=angular%20file%20upload) will give you quite a few modules that you can check out to see which better fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I am getting some ideas